# how do we disable the button,when particular list item occurred for 5 times in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a list in vb,say items are

1. Apple
2. Apple
3. orange
4. Apple
5. Apple

Apple item in the list occurred for 5 times.
any particular item can only be added not more than 5 times in the list.
so,now it should disable the apple button,so that the user cannot add to the list.

Comment: Which is it: vb.net or vb6? They are **very** different animals.

Answer (score 0):

try this .... initialize a DS and count the number of times it gets repeated. Then if the condition given is false, Button.IsEnabled = False

Comment: what do u mean by DS here @krishna

Comment: `Structure Example
        Public count as Integer
        Public name as String
End Structure`

this is a data structure you can use in VB.NET ... So while displaying the list, if you check the structure while displaying the list of options, that would be great.